# (Flutter) How to track user location(lat,long) when the app is killed and store in database after every 1min?

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, location, background-process

I want to create a project that tracks the user's location when the app is closed or the app is running and then sends user data to mysql database. I chose Flutter to create this project. I'm new in flutter. How to I develop this application? Help me with some advice or related guidelines so I can develop this application.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) could help you with it. [Check the example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example) too

Comment: i can't understand can you please give another example